# Enable Tablet support for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, touch

Currently have this method to enable touch functions in the wpf app it works except that we lose the ability to scroll datagrid with touch (directly on the datagrid), the scrollbar works fine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/disable-the-realtimestylus-for-wpf-applications

```
public static void DisableWPFTabletSupport()  
{  
    // Get a collection of the tablet devices for this window.
    TabletDeviceCollection devices = System.Windows.Input.Tablet.TabletDevices;  


if (devices.Count > 0)  
{
    // Get the Type of InputManager.  
    Type inputManagerType = typeof(System.Windows.Input.InputManager);  


// Call the StylusLogic method on the InputManager.Current instance.  
object stylusLogic = inputManagerType.InvokeMember("StylusLogic",  
            BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,  
            null, InputManager.Current, null);  

if (stylusLogic != null)  
{  
    //  Get the type of the stylusLogic returned from the call to StylusLogic.  
    Type stylusLogicType = stylusLogic.GetType();  

    // Loop until there are no more devices to remove.  
    while (devices.Count > 0)  
    {  
        // Remove the first tablet device in the devices collection.  
        stylusLogicType.InvokeMember("OnTabletRemoved",  
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,  
                null, stylusLogic, new object[] { (uint)0 });  
    }
}  

}  
}
```

We are wondering what the "opposite" of that function would be, to enable it again.

Comment: Can you show the xaml?